# Почему не работает stroke-dashoffset анимации круга?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
      Фон серого цвета
 <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)'  stroke-dashoffset='314' stroke-dasharray='314' stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate 
  attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='0,314;314,0'
  fill='freeze'
  />
 </circle>
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь анимировать `stroke-dashoffset` он задается одним числом, а в атрибут `values` поставили пары значений, видимо скопировали с атрибута `stroke-dasharray`

сделайте так:

`values='314;0'`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
      Фон серого цвета
 <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)'  stroke-dashoffset='314' stroke-dasharray='314' stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate 
  attributeName='stroke-dashoffset'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='314;0'
  fill='freeze'
  />
 </circle>
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. В ответе **@Stranger in the Q**  для анимации использован атрибут `stroke-dashoffset`
   при значениях `values="314;0"`, что соответствует изменению отступа начала линии от максимального значения (314) до нуля. Реализуя тем самым анимацию рисование линии от нуля до максимума (полный круг)
2. При анимации `stroke-dasharray` используется также два значения `values="0, 314;314, 0`
   **стартовое значение анимации** - `0, 314`, где 0 - длина черты, 314 - длина пробела поэтому линию в начале не видно.
   **финальное значение анимации** - `314, 0`, где   314 длина черты. поэтому линия будет нарисована полностью

Поэтому  ваш код был изначально верный, но допущена одна ошибка: вместо `stroke-dashoffset` нужно было написать `stroke-dasharray`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
      Фон серого цвета
 <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)'  stroke-dashoffset='314' stroke-dasharray='314' stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate 
 attributeName='stroke-dasharray'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='0,314;314,0'
  fill='freeze'
  />
 </circle>
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text> 
</svg>
```

На мой взгляд анимация с помощью `stroke-dasharray` содержит больше возможностей.

Например, использовав две пары параметров `stroke-dasharray`,  можно сделать ту же анимацию заполнения круга двумя отдельными линиями из одной точки

**values="0, 157 0, 157; 0, 0, 314, 0"**

**stroke-dashoffset="0"**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
      Фон серого цвета
 <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)'  stroke-dashoffset='0' stroke-dasharray='0, 157 0, 157' stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate 
 attributeName='stroke-dasharray'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='0, 157 0, 157; 0, 0, 314, 0'
  fill='freeze'
  />
 </circle>
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text> 
</svg>
```

*Другой вариант*
при **stroke-dashoffset="157"**
Стартовая точка анимации сдвигается на половину окружности

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
      Фон серого цвета
 <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' stroke-dasharray="0, 157 0, 157"  stroke-dashoffset="157"  stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate 
 attributeName='stroke-dasharray'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='0, 157 0, 157; 0, 0, 314, 0'
  fill='freeze'
  />
 </circle>
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text> 
</svg>
```

Изменяя stroke-dashoffset можно начать анимацию из любой точки окружности

Например при `stroke-dashoffset="78.5"` стартовая точка сдвигается на четверть окружности `314 / 4 = 78.5`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"   
     width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 120 120" >  
      Фон серого цвета
 <rect width='100%' height='100%' fill='grey'/>
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' stroke='white' stroke-width='8' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' />
 <circle r='50' cx='60' cy='60' fill='none' transform='rotate(-90 60 60)' stroke-dasharray="0, 157 0, 157"  stroke-dashoffset="78.5"  stroke='dodgerblue' stroke-width='8'>
  <animate 
 attributeName='stroke-dasharray'
  dur='4s'
  begin='svg1.click'
  values='0, 157 0, 157; 0, 0, 314, 0'
  fill='freeze'
  />
 </circle>
<text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor='middle' font-size='20' fill="">click</text> 
</svg>
```

Comment: __values="0, 157 0, 157; 0, 0, 314, 0"__ где 0 длина черты, 157 - длина пробела 0 длина черты, 157 - длина пробела; 0 длина черты 0 длина пробела  314- длина черты 0 длина пробела  ?

Comment: Почему последних в двух примерах начало анимации происходит в разных местах ?

Comment: @Leks Анимация начинается в разных местах, так как примеры имеют разные значения stroke-dashoffset  Добавил пример и описание в ответ В первом  вашем комментарии написано все правильно

Comment: понятно спасибо большое